# Selenium Python handling dropdown menus using key input

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium and trying to open a dropdown menu using Selenium.
The problem is that I cannot access the dropdown menu by id or something like this, because I want the program to do the same steps on different websites with exactly the same structure. Therefore I just want to give the program a starting point by ID (of a field) for each website, change the value in this field -> hit TAB twice -> hit enter, or click to open the dropdown. Everything works fine until implementing the last step. If I add the
`label_element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`
the TAB commands do not work anymore (It doesn't move on to the next field) and it just saves the website instead.
My code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


def prices(driver):
    counter = 0

    label_element = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'products_5_751_price_new')
    label_element.click()
    label_element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')
    label_element.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)
    label_element.send_keys("3,70")

    number = 2
    actions = ActionChains(driver) 
    for _ in range(number):
        actions = actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
    actions.perform()

    #label_element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

#option to keep the browser open after its done
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

def klick_it(choice, system):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
                              options=options)
    
    print (system)
    if system == "live":
        driver.get("https://xyz.de/backend.php/login")
        driver.maximize_window()

        username_field = driver.find_element(by="name", value="_username")
        password_field = driver.find_element(by="name", value="_password")

        username_field.send_keys("xyz")
        password_field.send_keys("xyz")
        password_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    elif system == "test":
        driver.get("https://xyz.de/backend.php/login")
        driver.maximize_window()
        username_field = driver.find_element(by="name", value="_username")
        password_field = driver.find_element(by="name", value="_password")

        username_field.send_keys("xyz")
        password_field.send_keys("xyz")
        password_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    next_click = driver.find_element(by="css selector", value="a.inner-dimension[title='Produkte und Tarife']")
    next_click.click()

    next_click = driver.find_element(by="css selector", value="a[title='MobileTickets']")
    next_click.click()

    if choice == 1:
        next_click = driver.find_element(by="css selector", value="a[title='Einzelfahrkarten']")
        next_click.click()

        tr_element = driver.find_element(by="css selector", value="tr.odd")
        tr_element.click()
        prices(driver)

    elif choice == 2:
        next_click = driver.find_element(by="css selector", value="a[title='Tageskarten']")
        next_click.click()
        element_to_click = driver.find_element(by="css selector", value="a[href='/backend.php/product/386/edit']")  
        element_to_click.click()
    
    #... not relevant just more elifs
```

I hope the problem is understandable.
Red arrows are TAB steps
[image]

Comment: I found out that it still applies the TAB key twice. But once I (or the Selenium) press the ENTER Key it jumps back to the first input field and saves the page.